# How can I get a Nest Thermostat to report when the heater is on and when the cooler is on

Tags: nest-thermostat

I've seen settings for my Nest Thermostat to notify based on specific temperatures or when home or away, but I haven't figured out a way to get info on when the house is currently heating or when it is cooling.

Is there a way to do this? I assume I would need to buy some kind of hub, but which hub?

Comment: Do you want remote monitoring, e.g. actively use an app/page to see what's going on, or are you interested in a notification, e.g. "started/stopped heating"?

Comment: What I want to do with the info is irrelevant to the question. Both cases you pointed out would depend on Nest sending the info I'm interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which supports the older Nest [Thermostat API](https://developers.nest.com/reference/api-thermostat) will have access to [hvac_state](https://developers.nest.com/reference/api-thermostat#hvac_state) which tells you if the HVAC is "heating", "cooling" or "off".

Anything that supports the newer [Smart Device Management API](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/reference/rest) will have access to the [thermostat-hvac](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/traits/device/thermostat-hvac) trait which does the same.